# SSRS parameter with @

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

How I can pass SSRS parameter with @? When I am trying to choose email from parameter list, I get:

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
Parser: The syntax for '@xx' is incorrect. (ASF@xx.com).
```

I need it to filter my MDX dataset.

Answer (score 1):

The values in cubes uses are not simply text, they are members of a dimension with attributes. In order to make the comparison, it needs to be converted to the proper syntax. A good way to add a parameter is to use the SSRS Query Designer.

1. Go to your Dataset properties.
2. Click on Query Designer.
3. Drag the attribute to the top-right corner.
4. Check the box in the Parameters column.
5. Click OK.

This will create a hidden dataset along with the parameter. It also formats the dropdown list for you.

If you look in the MDX it creates, there is a `StrToSet` function that it uses to interpret the string.

Another option that is simpler, but less efficient is to simply apply the filter to your dataset within SSRS.

1. Go to the Dataset properties.
2. Go to the Filters tab.
3. Add a filter that ensures the `Email` column equals your `Parameters!Email.Value`

Comment: It works only for one parameter. Even if I change operator to "in", only first email is send to filter.

Comment: If you add parameters through the Query Designer they accept multiple values by default. If you are adding a filter expression, just make sure there's no "(0)" after `Parameters!Email.Value`.